Help me prove me the following claim: $NP = coNP$ Iff $coNP \cup NP$ is closed under intersection
I was able to prove the first direction which is the assumption that $NP=coNP$, but I am unable to prove the second direction:
Assuming that the union group is closed, how can it be proved that $NP=coNP$?

Hint: Assume that $\mathrm{NP} \neq \mathrm{coNP}$, and take a languge $A \in \mathrm{NP} \setminus \mathrm{coNP}$. Now consider the languages $A_0 = \{0w \mid w \in A\} \cup 1\{0,1\}^*$ and $A_1 = 0\{0,1\}^* \cup \{1w \mid w \notin A\}$.

Actually I couldn't figure it out despite the hint, I would like to get a clearer hint.
Thank you

@NirBinjamin It should be pretty straight-forward from here. There isn't much you could sensibly do with these languages in order to answer the question, and the most obvious thing is going to work out.
